# Android ICS Virtual Button Rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screen-orientation, softkeys

Is it possible to rotate the virtual buttons (soft keys) programmatically?

I understand that if I enable android:screenOrientation options I can get these buttons to auto-rotate. But sometimes my activity is too heavy to rotate everything. So I am seeking solutions to keep some screen items intact while rotating the virtual buttons to the correct display orientation.

I couldn't find any documentation and/or mention of related APIs/hacks. Is this a forbidden realm?

Answer (score 0):

Android detects orientation/nav bar positioning in the PhoneWindowManager which is part of the framework code.  So unfortunately it's not possible to do this from an app.